# Can't import PMD Ruleset in Eclipse

Tags: import, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, rules, pmd

I would like to use the same Ruleset in my IDE (Eclipse) that my Sonar profile.

I got the PMD XML ruleset from the Sonar Permalinks and would like to import it into my PMD Eclipse Plugin but when i try to do it, the "OK" button is desactivated ...

[image: Can't import a PMD Ruleset in PMD Eclipse Plugin]

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem could be that Sonar is exporting your ruleset for v4.x format and your Eclipse plugin expects them in v5.x format.

Try changing your rules from:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
```

to

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals">
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
```

Please note the **ref** attribute. A simple find and replace all will work out fine for you.

Comment: Just tried this with SonarQube 3.7 and Eclipse Kepler and it didn't work. Any updates on this answer?

Comment: Also, you may also have to use Dove and KrishPrabakar answers below.  Additionally, the following also changed -    The rules UnusedPrivateField, UnusedLocalVariable, UnusedPrivateMethod, UnusedFormalParameter, UnusedModifier moved from controversial.xml to unusedcode.xml. The rule design.xml/UseSingleton changed to design.xml/UseUtilityClass

Answer (score 3):

The advice from Ivan Nikolov helped me, but I had to also change one rule from:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml/UnusedModifier">
  <priority>5</priority>
</rule>
```

to

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedModifier">
  <priority>5</priority>
</rule>
```

Here is my PMD configuration file from sonar which is working for me with PMD-plugin 4.0.2.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         name="pmd-eclipse"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/StringInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/ConstructorCallsOverridableMethod">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingNPE">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidRethrowingException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/ReplaceEnumerationWithIterator">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml/AvoidArrayLoops">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedFormalParameter">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/ClassCastExceptionWithToArray">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingNullPointerException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedPrivateField">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/CompareObjectsWithEquals">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UseIndexOfChar">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/BigIntegerInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/FinalFieldCouldBeStatic">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/SuspiciousEqualsMethodName">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/InstantiationToGetClass">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/SuspiciousHashcodeMethodName">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/coupling.xml/LooseCoupling">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedLocalVariable">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UnnecessaryCaseChange">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/SingularField">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/CloseResource">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingThrowable">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/CollapsibleIfStatements">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UselessOperationOnImmutable">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/clone.xml/CloneMethodMustImplementCloneable">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UselessOverridingMethod">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedModifier">
    <priority>5</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/PreserveStackTrace">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml/UseArraysAsList">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/EqualsNull">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/BrokenNullCheck">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-jakarta-commons.xml/UseCorrectExceptionLogging">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/InefficientStringBuffering">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/sunsecure.xml/ArrayIsStoredDirectly">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/FinalizeOverloaded">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml/DontImportSun">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml/DontImportJavaLang">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/MissingStaticMethodInNonInstantiatableClass">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/StringBufferInstantiationWithChar">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml/UseArrayListInsteadOfVector">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/StringToString">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/SimplifyConditional">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/ReplaceVectorWithList">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml/NcssMethodCount">
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
      <property name="minimum" value="50" />
    </properties>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml/AvoidPrintStackTrace">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/MethodWithSameNameAsEnclosingClass">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/SuspiciousConstantFieldName">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml/NcssTypeCount">
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
      <property name="minimum" value="800" />
    </properties>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/AvoidInstanceofChecksInCatchClause">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/IntegerInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/AvoidAssertAsIdentifier">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/UnnecessaryLocalBeforeReturn">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/AvoidCallingFinalize">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/BooleanInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnconditionalIfStatement">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/clone.xml/CloneThrowsCloneNotSupportedException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/ReplaceHashtableWithMap">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/AvoidDecimalLiteralsInBigDecimalConstructor">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/EmptyFinalizer">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/IdempotentOperations">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/ExceptionAsFlowControl">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/FinalizeDoesNotCallSuperFinalize">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UseStringBufferLength">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/AvoidEnumAsIdentifier">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml/SystemPrintln">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UselessStringValueOf">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/AvoidDuplicateLiterals">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the language to my XPath rule(s) as well, e.g:

```
<rule name="DontUseDate" language="java" class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule" ...></rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Nikolov's answer is correct. Your problem are different versions of ruleset format . In my case I was trying to import ruleset exported from PMD plugin version 3.2.6 into plugin version 4.0.0. Here are my findings:

- Path change that Ivan Nikolov mentioned is needed for all the rules. Be careful because not all the rules belong to java (I saw also rules for XML,...). I am not that deep into PMD, so I don't know in which version were rules for other technologies introduced.
- It is useful to export default ruleset of PMD plugin 4.0.0 for comparison with old custom ruleset file. This way you can fix problems that can be spotted at next point.
- During your behavior was thrown exception that wasn't visualized. This exception can be seen in your workspace log file (/.metadata/.log) at the end. This can give you a clue what else needs to be changed. Use the previous point to find out how to fix problems. In my case it was changed path of one rule from 

  to

After these changes I was able to import manually migrated custom ruleset file into PMD plugin 4.0.0.

Hope this helps.

BTW: I find 4.0.0 version of PMD plugin very buggy so I downgraded back to 3.2.6

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others said, you may also have to find this:

```
net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.XPathRule
```

and replace it by this:

```
net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [Sonar Eclipse](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse) ? You wouldn't need to worry about synchronization of rule sets.

Comment: But with Sonar Eclipse it will take a long time to run the complet test. Here i want to use the 3 individual plugins (PMD, CheckStyle, Findbugs) because I can run it on a particular package .. (Thanks for your help)

Comment: Well, ok... So sorry, I can't help you more on this as PMD Eclipse is out of my scope. Just as an information: we're working hard to improve Sonar Eclipse to be able to run incremental analyses :)

Comment: It will really be a great feature ! Big thanks for your help ! It can also be interesting to have Sonar "Warnings" directly in his IDE (Eclipse). Because it's really boring to see an issue on the Sonar WebServer and then to have to search for the concerned lines of code in his IDE ...  :-)

Comment: Euuuh, aren't you talking about this: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Working+with+Sonar+in+Eclipse#WorkingwithSonarinEclipse-ManagingExistingViolations?

Comment: I'm also having trouble with Sonar Eclipse. The analyzes take too long because they are performed for the entire project. It would be really great having automatic and incremental analysis.
Do you know if it is already being implemented? Any predictions on when will be available?